# Outputs on my SQL command line are shown is a weird manner. Can someone help me to fix it?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

when I try to print the contents in a table, it prints it like this. I have no clue why is this happening.

[image]

I am using Oracle SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0

I am a noob in SQL so I apologize if this is a trivial problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line is *too short*; make it longer with e.g.

```
set linesize 100
```

Then run your query again. If 100 is still too short, enlarge it.

---

Before:

```
SQL> select * from emp where rownum < 2;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        920
        20
```

After:

```
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> select * from emp where rownum < 2;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        920                    20

SQL>
```

Comment: In addition, worth pointing out that the need for enlarging the LINESIZE can be somewhat mitigated by adjusting the size of overly-long columns.  In this example 'COL JOB FORMAT A10' will shorten the width of the JOB column, thus shortening the requirements for the total line.